# Angular Universal error - app.auth is not a function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2, angular-universal

**Tech Stack:** AngularFire2, Firebase, Firebase Functions, Angular 7,

I get an error when I deploy the website into Firebase Functions, although it works properly locally.

Angular Cli and Angular Universal.

```
AngularFire2 version: "@angular/fire": "^5.1.2"
Firebase version:    "firebase": "^5.9.3"
```

I have debugged this and it seems to be an issue with AngularFire2.

**Things I've tried:**

I have upgraded the library and downgraded it to see if that fixes it, but no luck.

Also, tried uninstall npm packages and removing the package lock but no luck either.

**This is the stack trace error on firebase console (functions):**

```
ERROR TypeError: app.auth is not a function
    at /user_code/dist/server.js:152999:24
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/user_code/dist/server.js:555:26)
    at Zone.run (/user_code/dist/server.js:314:43)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (/user_code/dist/server.js:20244:28)
    at new AngularFireAuth (/user_code/dist/server.js:152997:26)
    at _createClass (/user_code/dist/server.js:24259:20)
    at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/dist/server.js:24221:26)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (/user_code/dist/server.js:24185:21)
    at _createClass (/user_code/dist/server.js:24251:29)
    at _createProviderInstance (/user_code/dist/server.js:24221:26)
```

**This is my current webpack.prerender.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const regex = /firebase\/(app|firestore)/;

module.exports = {
  mode: 'none',
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: { extensions: ['.ts', '.js'] },
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'app'
  },
   // this makes sure we include node_modules and other 3rd party libraries
  externals: [function(context, request, callback) {

    // exclude firebase products from being bundled, so they will be loaded using require() at runtime.
    if(regex.test(request)) {
      return callback(null, 'commonjs ' + request);
    }
    callback();
  }],
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
      {
        // Mark files inside `@angular/core` as using SystemJS style dynamic imports.
        // Removing this will cause deprecation warnings to appear.
        test: /(\\|\/)@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/).+\.js$/,
        parser: { system: true },
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
};
```

Comment: Has been a long time since I worked with AngularFire (2017). But I remembered of having to encapsulate it with a proxy that would switch to the Firebase REST API when doing server-side rendering. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain how I would do that @FelipeGonçalvesMarques

Comment: You would do two implementations of a FirebaseService, one using AngularFire and other using HttpClient. Both should receive the same config object and should have the exact same interface. Then you would have a Proxy or a Builder that would receive a flag indicating if you are on the server-side or client-side. According to the flag you would choose which implementation of FirebaseService to use. I'm not sure, but I believe you can use Angular Dependency Injection to use a Function to decide with implementation to inject.

Comment: @FelipeGonçalvesMarques do you have a stackblitz example for me?

Comment: I can try to put one together, but I would be able to do that only in the end of the week. And again, I'm  not sure this is the cause of your problem. I took a look in AngularFire2 github, and according to their README, they support server-side rendering. So, I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I wonder if its something to do with my webpack config: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1707

Comment: @FelipeGonçalvesMarques I've added my webpack config above. Can you take a look and see if the error is related to that config please?

Comment: Why do you do this?
`if(regex.test(request)) {
      return callback(null, 'commonjs ' + request);
    }`

Comment: No Idea, I grabbed it from another webpack config, should I remove it?

Comment: yep, I'll give a proper answer, just a sec

Comment: Should I try this webpack config: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codediodeio/angular-firestarter/master/webpack.prerender.config.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191656/discussion-between-felipe-goncalves-marques-and-angularm).

Comment: Try just removing the `externals` property form the webpack config.

Comment: If I remove externals, I get this error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. TypeError: Cannot read property 'stringify' of undefined

Comment: Let's talk on the SO chat, this way we don't extend the discussion in the comments: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191656/discussion-between-felipe-goncalves-marques-and-angularm

Comment: What was missing in the functions package.json?

Comment: "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },

Comment: @FelipeGonçalvesMarques I have one more ssr issue with rendering, I've made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634099/angular-universal-ssr-not-work-for-pages-that-use-firebase-firestore-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for this issue:

"engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },

was missing from the package.json file in the functions folder.
It seems that with this missing, causes the html not to fully render with ssr.